# C# Methods not printing proper values

Tags: c#, variables, selenium

I have two methods General and SearchTab below. When I look at my report file, I see that the values for the General Methods as:

TestName:

TestMachine: Maya

TestUser: Administrator

TestTime: 6/13/2011 12:02

TestStatus: FAIL

TestExpectedResult:

TestActualResult:

TestComments:

TestName, TestExpectedResult, TestActualResult, and TestComments are blank whereas they should have values:

TestName: Test 1: General,

TestExpectedResult: 'Home' tab should be present,

TestActualResult: Home tab found

TestComments: Home tab found

Also, the TestStatus should have been PASS instead of FAIL.

It looks like even though I reassigned the values of these variables in the method General, they are still printing the values that were assigned to them inside the constructor.

The problem is the same for the second method SearchTab.

Please help me figure out the problem.

```
namespace Automation
{
[TestClass]
public class FunctionalTest
{
    public ISelenium Sel;
    public StringBuilder Err;
    public string Report = "C:\Report.XLS";
    public string[] arrTestResults = new string[8];
    public string TestName;
    public string TestMachine;
    public string TestUser;
    public string TestTime;
    public string TestStatus;
    public string TestExpectedResult;
    public string TestActualResult;
    public string TestComments;

    // Constructor
    public FunctionalTest()
    {

        TestName = arrTestResults[0];
        TestMachine = arrTestResults[1] = System.Environment.MachineName.ToString();
        TestUser = arrTestResults[2] = System.Environment.UserName.ToString();
        TestTime = arrTestResults[3] = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
        TestStatus = arrTestResults[4] = "FAIL";
        TestExpectedResult = arrTestResults[5];
        TestActualResult = arrTestResults[6];
        TestComments = arrTestResults[7];
    }

    public void WriteReport(string[] arrResults)
    {
        int iLastRow, iCnt1;

        if (File.Exists(Report))
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Excel.Range range;

            Object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Report, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            iLastRow = range.Rows.Count;
            for (iCnt1 = 1; iCnt1 < 9; iCnt1++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[iLastRow + 1, iCnt1] = arrResults[iCnt1 - 1];
            }
            xlWorkBook.Save();
            xlApp.Quit();
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Report File " + Report + " does not exist");
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void General()
    {
        TestName = "Test 1: General";
        TestExpectedResult = "'Home' tab should be present";
        if (Sel.IsElementPresent("TAB_Home")))
        {

                TestStatus = "PASS";
                TestActualResult = "Home tab found";
                TestComments = TestActualResult;
        }
            else
            {
                TestActualResult = "Home tab not found";
                TestComments = TestActualResult;

            }

            //Write to report
            WriteReport(arrTestResults);
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SearchTab()
    {
        TestName = "Test 2: Search Tab";
        TestExpectedResult = "Search tab should be present";
        // Assigning TestStatus to FAIL because TestStatus is PASS right now from the previous test method
        TestStatus = "FAIL";

        if (Sel.IsElementPresent("TAB_Search"))
        {
            sActual = "Search Tab found";
            arrTestResults[7] = sActual;
            TestComments = TestActualResult;
            TestStatus = "PASS";
        }
        else
        {
            TestActualResult = "Search tab not found";
            TestComments = TestActualResult;
        }

        //Write to report
        WriteReport(arrTestResults);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: About 90% of this code is irrelevant (to the question). Why do you think Test 1 (TestName?)  should "print" general?  Find the lines.

Comment: TestName = "Test 1: General";

Comment: WriteReport(arrTestResults);                                                 It is being printed in an excel file. public string Report = "C:\Report.XLS";    public void WriteReport(string[] arrResults)

Comment: And at the moment you call that, `TestName == "Test 1: General"`but `arrTestResults[0] == null`. The problem lays with your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intialization creates the initial array values and never changes them.  You are changing the field values:

```
string TestName = "test";

TestName = arrTestResults[0];

// At this point, changing TestName does not affect arrTestResults[0]
```

Also, you should not use public fields.  Rather, you should use properties.

```
public string TestName { get; set; }  // auto-property
```

OR

```
private string _testName = string.Empty;
public string TestName { get { return _testName; } set { _testName = value; }}
```

You either need to write a setter for your properties that change the array, or better yet use the appropriate fields/properties in your report:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[iLastRow + 1, 0] = TestName;
```

Of course, this could be refactored to be much better as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't assign values in constructor or in General method. As per your code, General seems to be a test case. If it is test case, then do not expect General should be called first because you defined that as a first method.

Use SetupTest() to set the value. Note that SetupTest() is not a test case, but it is will be called before executing your each test case.

Don't print, raise alert..

```
[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
  ...your initialization code...
}
```

Comment: One question though, is [Setup] and [TestInitialize] the same?

Comment: TestInitialize runs before every test on the other hand Setup will runs only once for the full test suite.

Comment: I tried using the [Setup] and also the [TestInitialize]. But when my methods call the WriteReport(arrTestResults) function for each of the methods (test cases), my excel report file still shows blanks values like I mentioned in my question. I will be changing the values of the variables for each method (test case). So, how should I use [Setup]?